# how to get the host home directory path in node docker container using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, docker, home-directory

```
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
```

The above code segment gives the current home directory easily when the application runs on the host machine. After dockerizing, it returns "root" as the home directory and it should be probably the docker container's home directory. How can I get the current host machine home directory path from node container?

Comment: You can’t: a key goal of Docker is that the host filesystem and container filesystems are isolated from each other (as are their user ID spaces, network namespaces, and other details).  If accessing the currently logged in user’s home directory is important to your application, Docker isn’t an appropriate packaging mechanism.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have developed a blockchain project which stores credentials in host machine file system. After that, I developed a backend client using docker. Now I need to get that credentials to the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I can't even imagine why you would want such a functionality :) Imagine you download such an image from a public repository and you run it on your own machine...

In any case, you can achieve this is you pass the current directory as an environment variable or an inline parameter to your program when you do `docker run`. So you would have to explicitly pass this information to the container when you create it.